# Using differentiation under the integral sign to evaluate $\int\ln(x^n+1) \,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

This is my first stack exchange question, so sorry if it is not neat. So for
$$\int\ln(x^n+1)\,\mathrm dx,
$$
I tried doing $\ln(a(x^n + 1))$ where $a = 1$ and differentiating under the integral. So I set the integral is $Q(a)$ and get
$$
Q^\prime(a)=\int 1/a\,\mathrm dx
$$
because we treat $(x^n + 1)$ like a coefficient. And then $Q^\prime(a) = dQ/da=x/a$, so $Q = x\ln(a) + C$ but setting $a = 1$ you get $Q(1) = C$ and the derivative of $C$ is $0$, which isn't $\ln(x^n + 1)$. So what did I do wrong?

Comment: So you want to calculate $\frac{d}{dn} \int\limits_0^{\infty} \ln(x^n+1) \  dx$ ? If not, please explain.

Comment: I want to use differentiation under integral sign to calculate the integral. Like calculate the thing in your comment and find the antiderivative to find the integral. Sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: Please post the expression. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) are some formatting tips. For instance, the code of my expression is \frac{d}{dn} \int\limits_0^{\infty} \ln(x^n+1) \  dx

Comment: Okay I did_____

Comment: I don't remember exactly the hypothesis of the theorem of derivation under the integral sign, but I'm pretty sure you can't apply it for indefinite integrals

Comment: And don't expect to find a solution for the indefinite integral, it does not have a solution in terms of elementarty functions.

Comment: You can’t use differentiation under the integral sign for indefinite integrals, however you could consider $\int (x^n+1)^s \, dx$ as a binomial series and compute that integral then take the partial derivative with respect to $s$ then take $s\to0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake was in failing to recognize that $$Q(x,a)=x\ln(a)+xC(a)+k(x).$$ You assumed $C$ is a constant function, but it is not. The way this works is that $$Q(x,a)=\int\ln[a(x^n+1)]\,\mathrm{d}x,$$ so $$\frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{a}}(x,a)=\int\frac1{a}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int{f(x,a)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{x}}(x,a)\,\mathrm{d}x,$$ and since $$f(x,a)=\frac1{a}$$ implies $$g(x,a)=\frac{x}{a}+c(a),$$ you have that $$\frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{a}}(x,a)=\frac{x}{a}+c(a),$$ hence $$Q(x,a)=x\ln(a)+x\int{c(a)}\,\mathrm{d}a+k(x)=x\ln(a)+xC(a)+k(x).$$ We know that $$\frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{x}}(x,a)=\ln[a(x^n+1)],$$ and from the answer above, one can conclude that $$\frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{x}}(x,a)=\ln(a)+C(a)+k'(x),$$ we can thus conclude $$\ln(a)+\ln(x^n+1)=\ln(a)+C(a)+k'(x),$$ which leaves you with $C(a)=0,$ and $$k'(x)=\ln(x^n+1)=Q(x,1),$$ which is the very thing you were trying to find in the beginning.

The method is fundamentally flawed, because to begin with, $$\ln[a(x^n+1)]=\ln(a)+\ln(x^n+1),$$ so necessarily, $$Q(x,a)=x\ln(a)+Q(x,1),$$ so this variant of Feynman's technique useless in this instance.